# SAS: Drawing cards - find the first n occurences of unique names in two different variables

Tags: sql, sas

In SAS, I have a dataset "draworder" where each row identifies a person who tries to draw a card of a particular colour. I have two other datasets "cards_allowed" and "cards_available" showing how many cards each person can have (regardless of colour) and how many cards of each colour is avaiable.

I would like to go through the "draworder" dataset and flag which of the attempted draws that are successful. A draw is successful if the person has not reached the limit of how many cards they can hold AND if there are still cards available of the colour they try to draw.

The datasets I have are (simplified example):

```
* Dataset specifying the order each person tries to draw of each colour;
data draworder;
length person card $20;
input person $ card $;
datalines;
Alice   Red 
Charles Blue
Charles Red 
Ben     Blue
Alice   Blue
Ben     Blue
Ben     Red 
;
run;

* Dataset specifying how many cards each person can hold;
data cards_allowed;
length person $20;
input person $ handsize ;
datalines;
Alice   2
Ben     2
Charles 1
;
run;

* Dataset specifying how many cards are available of each colour;
data cards_available;
length card $20;
input card $ no_cards ;
datalines;
Red   2
Blue  3
;
run;
```

The dataset I want is a copy of "draworder" with the variable success_flag attached:

```
* I want to derive the variable "draw_fl" as "Y" when the person is able to draw 
  (card of the particular colour is avalable and hand is not full) and "N" otherwise;
data want;
length person card $20 success_flag $1;
input person $ card $ success_flag $;
datalines;
Alice   Red   Y
Charles Blue  Y
Charles Red   N
Ben     Blue  Y
Alice   Blue  Y
Ben     Blue  N
Ben     Red   Y
;
run;
```

Here, line 3 has a "N" because Charles already has drawn a card and he can only hold 1 according to the "cards_allowed" dataset. Line 6 has a "N" because there are no more blue cards.

In my actual problem I do not know the number of people (there may be between 10 and 20 rows in the "cards_allowed" dataset). I know there are always 3 different colours of cards.

I have tried attacking this problem using either symputx and resolve commands or using arrays and the vvaluex function, but I keep getting stuck. Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Is it the case that unkeepable cards are returned to available ? I.e. Charles Red is unkeepable and also 2nd red in deck.  Yet you say Ben Red is valid, and that is 3rd red drawn from deck, but only 2 red available!

Comment: Yes, if a draw is unsuccessful then the card stays on the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use two hashes.  One to track number of which card remains in deck and one to track number of cards left a player can hold.  Then it is just a matter of lookup remaining counts whilst evaluating the draw order.

Example:

```
* Dataset specifying the order each person tries to draw of each colour;
data draworder;
length person card $20;
input person $ card $;
datalines;
Alice   Red 
Charles Blue
Charles Red 
Ben     Blue
Alice   Blue
Ben     Blue
Ben     Red 
Dolly   Blonde
Jorge   Red
;
run;

* Dataset specifying how many cards each person can hold;
data cards_allowed;
length person $20;
input person $ handsize ;
datalines;
Alice   2
Ben     2
Charles 1
;
run;

* Dataset specifying how many cards are available of each colour;
data cards_available;
length card $20;
input card $ count ;
datalines;
Red   2
Blue  3
;
run;

data want(keep=person card status);
  length card $20 count 8 person $20 handsize 8 status $20;

  call missing(card, count, person, handsize);

  declare hash deck(dataset:'cards_available');
  deck.defineKey('card');
  deck.defineData('count');
  deck.defineDone();

  declare hash hands(dataset:'cards_allowed');
  hands.defineKey('person');
  hands.defineData('handsize');
  hands.defineDone();

  do until (lastdraw);
    set draworder end=lastdraw;
    if deck.find() = 0 then do;
      put card= count=;

      if count = 0 then do;
        *put 'ERROR:' card= 'is an impossible draw. No more in deck.';
        status = 'exhausted card';
      end;
      else do;
        if hands.find() = 0 then do;
          if handsize = 0 then do;
            status = 'full hand, why draw bro?';
          end;
          else do;
            handsize = handsize - 1;
            count = count - 1;
            hands.replace();
            deck.replace();
            status = 'Mine! Huzzah';
          end;
        end;
        else do;
          *put 'ERROR:' person= 'is not playing! Security!';
          status = 'imposter';
        end;
      end;

    end;
    else do;
      * put 'ERROR: drawn ' card= 'is not in deck';
      status = 'cheat card';
    end;

    output;
  end;
run;
```

Comment: This is both very helpful and very amusing code to read. Thanks a lot!